# What do you call a person who conducts seminar workshops?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If a *resource speaker* or *guest speaker* is someone who makes usually formal public speeches; a *trainer* is someone who trains; how about someone who conducts seminar workshops?

Comment: If he *conducts* workshops, perhaps he is the *conductor* of the workshops.

Comment: A *seminarian*, obviously.  (Well, maybe not.)

Comment: please describe what duties are included in your “conducts” verb.

Answer (score 8):

*Facilitator* is sometimes used to describe someone who leads a seminar.

> A facilitator is someone who helps a group of people understand their common objectives and assists them to plan to achieve them without taking a particular position in the discussion.
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facilitator_%28business%29)

Comment: What happened to all the 'instructors'?

Comment: Reg mentioned *instructor.* And instructors instruct; facilitators facilitate. A *seminar workshop* may not need an instructor.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Facilitator does leave it open that this person maybe wasn't present at the workshop. E.g. someone who made his building available and put up posters is a facilitator ([derived from the verb](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/facilitate)), but he does not necessarily conduct the workshop. Not saying your answer is wrong, just that it can have more interpretations than just the OP's.

Answer (score 7):

*Coach, instructor* or *tutor*. Will likely depend on what they want themselves to be called, and what kind of workshop it is.

Answer (score 0):

A person who conducts or presides over a seminar or group discussion may be called [*moderator*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moderator):

> one who presides over an assembly, meeting, or discussion.

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: Hello, Rajeswar. Your answer was (unfortunately) flagged automatically as low-quality for its length. Please try to cite some references as I've done in the edit. Your post seems to answer the question. Please review my edit and try to follow the format next time you answer a question. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

We call him **Organising Secretary**. He looks after all the aspects of the seminar - including funding, transportation, accommodation and publication from a direction and decision point of view.